# Editing formfields/references in word from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

Im using access to edit Word documents, and im using this code (example) to fill formfields in the document:

```
.FormFields("txtProsjektNavn").result = DLookup("txt", dbName, "key = 
'byggNavn'")
.FormFields("txtProsjektNr").result = DLookup("value1", dbName, "key = 
'prosjektNr'")
.FormFields("txtOverblikk").result = DLookup("txt", dbName, "key = 
'txtOverblikk'")
.FormFields("txtByggEier").result = DLookup("txt", dbName, "key = 
'byggEier'")
```

This is all working fine and dandy, however.
Some of these values needs to be repeated several times in the document.
Ive figured that giving 2 formfields the same bookmark name in the word document is a no-no. So instead of having to create lots of formfields with different names, i attempted to create REF fields that refered to the already made form fields, however, they do not update when access updates the formfields themselves.

Does anyone have a solution to this or do I simply need to make lots of formfields with different names, like: text1, text2, text3 and then have access fill them all with the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the suggested solution but my problem was that when i updated all the fields in the document the Form-fields reset to blank.
I worked around this by looping through the cross-reference fields only, and hitting update on them individually.

```
    docField as Word.Field

    For Each docField In doc.Fields
    If docField.Type = wdFieldRef Then
        docField.Update
    End If
    Next docField
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already filled in your required form fields. If you want to repeat these values you can use [cross-reference](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-cross-reference-300b208c-e45a-487a-880b-a02767d9774b)

Once you set all the fields following the steps below, then you can auto update fields using `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` after populating your form fields.

> Insert -> Cross-Reference(Under Links)

[image]

> Select Reference type as Bookmark and Insert

[image]

> Use `ActiveDocument.Fields.Update` in vba to update fields.

[image]

Comment: Hey! This was exactly what I was looking for, and I did give it a shot just now. Some issues however, after i run activedocument.fields.update, my form fields resets to blank. Which ofcourse leads to the cross-references being blank